# Powershell: Get all members and their groups that are members of a specific group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This sounds confusing. For instance. I have a group `Research`. I want all members of the Research group listed, and then each group that each of those users are in. Is there any way to do this?

Also, is there a way to get whether the group listed is a security group or distribution list as another column in the output?

For example, here is code I've been using, and I'd like for it to work as described above.

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

$myCol = @()
  ForEach ($Group in (Get-QADGroup "CN=RES,OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=fff,DC=com" -GroupType Security))
    {
    ForEach ($Member in (Get-QADGroupMember $Group -SizeLimit 0))
        { 
        $myObj = "" | Select Group, Member, Email
        $myObj.Group = $Group.Name
        $myObj.Member = $Member.Name
        $myObj.Email = $Member.Email
        $myCol += $myObj
        }
    }
  $myCol | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\sdevito\Desktop\1a.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It would help to give an example of the output in the format you want. Group memebership (memberof) is a multi-valued property, and those don't always lend themselves well to .csv. You'll need to decide if you want one row per user, with the membership list as a delimited string in one field, or if you want one row for each group membership, with multiple rows having the same user.

Comment: multiple rows having the same user would be best, since i need information about each group that each member belongs to

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for but sounds like you are looking to find out what groups a user in the parent group is part of you can do it with something like this:

```
if($Member.Type -eq "User"){Get-QADUser $Member.Name | Select MemberOf}
```

If you want to formate it better you could do:

```
Get-QADUser $object.Name | Select MemberOf | FL
```

If you want to know if a group is a Security group or Distribution group look at the sAMAccountType attribute:

```
Get-QADGroup $groupName -properties sAMAccountType
```

The sAMAccountType will be a bunch of numbers and it depends on the group type. Security and Dstirubtion listed here:
Security groups: 268435456
Distribution Group: 268435457

if you want to see more see this: [Link](http://chrisbeams.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/active-directory-samaccounttype/)

Hope this helps!